# how to Set the values of array object as selected in dropdown list(multiselect) using jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var selectedCity = [{ cityid:"1" }, { cityid:"3" }]
```

HTML:

```
City:<select name="city" multiple>
    <option value="1">Bombay</option>
    <option value="2">Chennai</option>
    <option value="3">Bangalore</option>
    <option value="4">Calcutta</option>
    <option value="5">Delhi</option>
     </select>
```

I have an array object ie selectedCity with the selected city values .

Now how to set these array values as selected in the dropdown list using jquery each function such that it has Bombay(1) and Bangalore(3) as selected in dropdown list box

Comment: please correct `cityid` in `Object { cityid="1"}, Object {cityidid="3"}`

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you should do it

```
 <select name="cars" multiple>
  <option selected="selected" value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select`>`
```

Comment: He has a completed select and want to change the val by an object from javascript... so this is not helpful

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
var values = [];
$.each(selectedCity, function( ){
    values.push(this.cityid);
});
$('select').val(values);
```

Create a list, push each val to the list and set it as val from the select.
Multiselect val takes as a list: `.val([1,3])`

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do it just send those names

## Javascript:

//loops through objects

```
for (var key in selectedCity) {
     $('select>option:eq(key.cityid)').prop('selected', true);

}
```

## HTML:

```
<select multiple>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I just can say again...He has a completed select and want to change the val by an object from javascript... so this is not helpful

Comment: for (var key in selectedCity.cityid) {
     $('select>option:eq(key)').attr('selected', true);
   
}
this should work

Comment: aditionally, i would prefer `.prop()`, because when you are using `.attr()` to change the checked state of a checkbox, it wont work well

Comment: That might work too ..  thanks @Mephiztopheles

Comment: can u explain it using .prop

Comment: `$('select>option:eq(key.cityid)').prop('selected', true);` :D

Comment: `.prop` can set states like `selected, checked, disabled ...` better than `.attr`. Better to read and better to set. To read, just use the first parameter as the state/attribute you want to read

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr
see here details